# how can we change .net framework 4.6.1 to .net core 3.1 into class library output type

Tags: asp.net

When i am trying to add .core reference dll into .net framework class library after build class library it showing me any error i.e. error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RMHClassLibrary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice and easier to answer, if you clarify your question and provide more information. I suppose you want multi-targeting. In this case, I suggest you to creare `.Net Standard`

[Support multiple .NET Framework versions in your project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file)